# how to find holes in objects in matlab image?

Tags: matlab, image-processing

is it possible to find holes in connected components, i.e in objects in an image. if so, can we also count holes? Like, I have used cc = bwlabel(image); to do connected components labeling. Now, how to find number of holes in each object ?

Answer (score 4):

You could use the Euler characteristic. From the Matlab documentation:

> The **bweuler** function returns the Euler number for a binary image. The Euler number is a measure of the topology of an image. It is defined as the total number of objects in the image minus the number of holes in those objects. You can use either 4- or 8-connected neighborhoods.

But be aware that a single pixel "hole" can change the Euler characteristic. You might want to use some opening/closing to smooth object outlines before using `bweuler`.

Answer (score 0):

A hole is the presence of nothing, so you can just invert the image and then count connected components.

Comment: No, i meant number of wholes present in a specific object.

Comment: Do you mean the number of connected components in the image?